# CSS - Body position:absolute bug?

Tags: css

Ok so I've been messing around with the css trying to get something just right.  Beforehand my script was essentially:

```
html, body {
height:100%;
}
body {
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
}
```

So I added position:absolute; in body, it didn't do what I was after so I removed it.  That's all I did.  Since then there's a margin/padding on the top of the site when there was none beforehand.  It's now happening in all browsers so it must be server-side, any ideas?

Comment: also, it worked just fine before and during position:absolute; - if i put it back it will work again, but it's not exactly a proper tag for body so i'd rather not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your issue:

```
.container, container2 {
...
}
```

Do you see it? *container2*...should be **.container2**

Advice you to use this: http://validator.w3.org/

Happy coding!

Comment: Wow, good eye!  That fixed it, not exactly sure why.  Thanks though :)

Comment: And of course good eye you used a validator, thanks eitherway. Didn't realize w3 made something like that, think I'll use it a lot.

Comment: Isn't `container2 {...` valid css? For example, if you created an HTML tag named `container2`? Why would that effect the position of the `body` tag?

Comment: no and no. if you do class="container2" it needs the class element of "." same as ID would need the "#" otherwise html cant determined what type of element it is